# $cordovaFileTransfer not working

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Am trying to user the $cordovaFileTransfer plugin from ngCordovato upload images in my ionic app.
However the images, never seem to upload. The app is running on my android phone and am debugging with chrome remote inspector, the network tab does not show any request for the upload.

This method gets images from the device

```
$scope.getImages = function() {
        var options = { 
            maximumImagesCount: 2,
            width: 800,
            height: 800,
            quality: 80
        };

        $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
        .then(function (results) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            $scope.queue.push({
                filepath: results[i],
                progress: 0.00
            });
          }
          $scope.$emit('process:queue');
        }, function(error) {
          // error getting photos
        });
    };
```

And am handling the 'process:queue' event with this method

```
$scope.startUploadQueue = function() {
        var server = encodeURI(serviceUrl());
        var options = {
            fileKey: "image",
            httpMethod: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer "+$user.getToken()
            }
        };

        angular.forEach($scope.queue, function(item) {
            $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, item.filepath, options, true)
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                $scope.media.push(result.data);
            }, function (error) {

            }, function (progress) {
                item.progress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
            });
        });
    };
```

Am doing something incorrectly?. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you try following code. http://pastebin.com/zw1uzufc

Just simple image upload without choosing from camera or gallery. so we just confirm your server upload code is right

Comment: It could be related to the whitelist settings. Is the endpoint already part of the settings?

Comment: Yeah the endpoint is the server variable